# Importing a specific column into phpmyadmin database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been given an excel document which contains information about different embassies, their contact numbers etc. Most of this information is in the database already, but I need to extract one column from this file (emails) and insert it into a specific column (emails) in the database.

Is this possible, or can you only import an exact copy of what you want in the database?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I think you need to use load data and import emails into an empty table. Once you've done it, you can use an update query making a join with this table in order to update your original table.

Comment: It is possible, for more help. Plz give more information with you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Export the table from phpmyadmin as CSV for excel - 
drag it into excel - 
add the desired column - 
Save - 
export the table again from phpmyadmin as .sql - 
copy the table creation(Not the data) - 
delete the table from phpmyadmin- 
Run the table creation query so you now have a blank table - 
Import the excel csv.
```

IMPORTANT: backup your database

Answer (score 2):

You may want to make a script with [php-excel-reader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/wiki/Documentation) which goes throught every row in the file, and updates the corresponding database row. I don't think that you can import a file "selectively" in phpMyAdmin.